# Exporting Hidden Column / Templated Column to Excel

Tags: c#, telerik

To display my data in grid I used a few template columns.

I have mutiple fields to display, like : `Name - Surname`.
But for doing an export as excel file, I need to split that information into 2 columns.
To apply filter in excel export..

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PRD_exp" Exportable="true"
                            HeaderText="Info1<br/>Info2" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#((myDataTYPE)Container.DataItem).Info1 %>
        <br/>-<br/>
        <%#((myDataTYPE)Container.DataItem).Info2 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

In my excel export I want that information to be in two different columns.
So I have set visibility of template column to `Exportable="false"`, and created it as a hidden column by making `visible="false"` for each data.

Like this:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Info1" UniqueName="Info1"
                         Exportable="true"  Visible="false" />
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Info2" UniqueName="Info2"
                         Exportable="true"  Visible="false" />
```

How can this be achieved, with the rad export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the change in your export button click event.

adding `GridUser.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Info1").Display=true` will do the trick.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridUser.ExportSettings.FileName = "ExportedFile;
    GridUser.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Info1").Display =true;
    GridUser.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Info2").Display = true; 
    GridUser.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = (GridExcelExportFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(GridExcelExportFormat), "Xlsx");
    GridUser.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
    GridUser.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    GridUser.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
    GridUser.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
}
```